# SDL_Color and SDL_Rect initialization

Tags: c++, sdl

So, I ran into a warning going by:

```
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

This is coming with my use of SDL_Color, as I'll show:

```
red = {255, 0, 0}
```

I know how to fix this warning, I just define it differently:

```
red.r = 255
```

And this works fine for basic colours but when it comes to Rect's and more complex colours I'm left wondering if there is a simpler, less time consuming solution that doesn't use as much space.

Comment: The compiler carefully gives you all necessary information to fix this warning. Have you read the message? Do you understand the message? Have you tried searching for details on the web?

Answer (score 0):

Uniform initialization is available only when C++11 is enabled in GCC. That's why you got this warning.

You have 2 possible solutions:

1. enable -std=c++11 in compiler settings\makefile.
2. write little helper functions, that will take params and return necessary structure.

More info about uniform initialization regarding structures is [available here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c19081/C-2011-Uniform-Initialization.htm)